# Detect points of change in sensor data

Tags: php, math, statistics

I have lots of sensor data from which I need to be able to detect changes reliably. Basically it comes from water level sensor in remote client. It's using accelerometer & float to get the water level. My problem is that the data can be noisy sometimes  (it varies by 2-5 units per measurement) and sometimes I need to detect changes as low as 7-9 units.

When I'm graphing the data it's quite obvious for human eye that there's a change but how would I go at it programming wise? Now I'm just trying to detect changes bigger than x programmatically but it's not too reliable. I've attached a sample graph and pointed the changes with arrows. The huge changes in the beginning are just testing, so it's not normal behaviour for data.

The data is in MYSQL database and the code is in PHP so if you could point me to right direction I'd highly appreciate it!

EDIT: Also there can be some spikes in the data which are not considered valid but rather a mistake in the data.

EDIT: Example data can be found from http://pastebin.com/x8C9AtAk
The algorithm would need to run every 30 mins or so and should be able to detect changes within the last 2-4 pings. Each ping is in 3-5min interval.

[image]

Comment: How about Kalman Filter?

Comment: How about giving us some data to play with? Not sure how frequent your samples are, so maybe upload the data to a different site and provide a link if there is a lot. Also, is it ok if the changes are only detected with the benefit of hindsight, or must they be detected "as the data arrives", or kind of "on the fly"?

Comment: You should look into [smoothing algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing). Another option would be transform a range of data points into a single data point by taking the average of that range of k data points. You would then compare every other data point looking to see if there is a significant change of average (greater than what could be accounted to error). If there is, the change likely occurs within the data point set between the two you checked. In any case, data to play with would help greatly.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added some data to play with to the original post. Changes can be detected with benefit of small hindsight, generally 2-4 data points after the occurrence but not much more.

Comment: @JakubKania Thanks! That looks a bit complicated though, looking slightly simpler solution if possible.

Comment: @Nuclearman Thanks. That could work. I'll try and see how it goes.

Comment: The only issue with the average approach is if you run the algorithm every x minutes and use that as the range, you'll only be able to detect changes that occurred x-2x minutes ago. You could certainly use the average of 2 data points, and be able to detect changes over 2-4 data points ago, but that carries a risk false positives and/or negatives. Although admittedly, it's also possible that during an interval, there is an upward and a downward change that cancel each other out. Thus the interval shouldn't be too large or too small. It also might be better to dynamically build the range.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I built a system which basically goes through datapoints and always gets average of  previous 4 points and average of current +2 next ones. This way the noise gets minimized and some kind of groups occur around each bigger change so those groups can be detected rather easily. It's relatively simple but seems to be working surprisingly well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some `awk` that you, or someone else, might like to experiment with. I average the last 10 (m) samples excluding the current one, and also average the last 2 samples (n) and then calculate the difference between the two and output a message if the absolute difference exceeds a threshold.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '
                                    # j will count number of samples
                                    # we will average last m samples and last n samples
   BEGIN {j=0;m=10;n=2}

   {d[j]=$3;id[j++]=$1" "$2}        # Store this point in array d[]

   END {                            # Do this at end after reading all samples
      for(i=m-1;i<j;i++){           # Iterate over all samples, except first few while building average

         totlastm=0                 # Calculate average over last m not incl current
         for(k=m;k>0;k--)totlastm+=d[i-k]
         avelastm=totlastm/m        # Average = total/m

         totlastn=0                 # Calculate average over last n
         for(k=n-1;k>=0;k--)totlastn+=d[i-k]
         avelastn=totlastn/n        # Average = total/n

         dif=avelastm-avelastn      # Calculate difference between ave last m and ave last n
         if(dif<0)dif=-dif          # Make absolute

         mesg="";
         if(dif>4)mesg="<-Change detected"; # Make message if change large
         printf "%s: Sample[%d]=%d,ave(%d)=%.2f,ave(%d)=%.2f,dif=%.2f%s\n",id[i],i,d[i],m,avelastm,n,avelastn,dif,mesg;
      }
   }
   ' <(tr -d '"' < levels.txt)
```

The last bit `<(tr...)` just removes the double quotes before sending the file `levels.txt` to `awk`.

Here is an excerpt from the output:

```
18393344 2014-03-01 14:08:34: Sample[1319]=343,ave(10)=342.00,ave(2)=342.00,dif=0.00
18393576 2014-03-01 14:13:37: Sample[1320]=343,ave(10)=342.10,ave(2)=343.00,dif=0.90
18393808 2014-03-01 14:18:39: Sample[1321]=343,ave(10)=342.10,ave(2)=343.00,dif=0.90
18394036 2014-03-01 14:23:45: Sample[1322]=342,ave(10)=342.30,ave(2)=342.50,dif=0.20
18394266 2014-03-01 14:28:47: Sample[1323]=341,ave(10)=342.20,ave(2)=341.50,dif=0.70
18394683 2014-03-01 14:38:16: Sample[1324]=346,ave(10)=342.20,ave(2)=343.50,dif=1.30
18394923 2014-03-01 14:43:17: Sample[1325]=348,ave(10)=342.70,ave(2)=347.00,dif=4.30<-Change detected
18395167 2014-03-01 14:48:25: Sample[1326]=345,ave(10)=343.20,ave(2)=346.50,dif=3.30
18395409 2014-03-01 14:53:28: Sample[1327]=347,ave(10)=343.60,ave(2)=346.00,dif=2.40
18395645 2014-03-01 14:58:30: Sample[1328]=347,ave(10)=343.90,ave(2)=347.00,dif=3.10
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out. However that has slight problem because if the sensor gets disturbed and there's a change but the water level goes back to what it was before then this code would result in false positive. I guess one approach could be to first find points of change and after that compare average of 5-10 data points before and after the change. Then one could exclude false positives rather simply. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

The right way to go about problems of this kind is to build a model of the phenomenon of interest and also a model of the noise process, and then make inferences about the phenomenon given some data. These inferences are necessarily probabilistic. The general computation you need to carry out is `P(H_k | data) = P(data | H_k) P(H_k) / (sum_k (P(data | H_k) P(H_k))` (a generalized form of Bayes rule) where the `H_k` are all the hypotheses of interest, such as "step of magnitude  at time " or "noise of magnitude ". In this case there might be a large number of plausible hypotheses, covering all possible magnitudes and times. You might need to limit the range of hypotheses considered in order to make the problem tractable, e.g. only looking back a certain number of time steps.